# How do I render different content on page based on different data within a database document with vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a firestore database with locations in it and I'm trying to have so that depending on which location is stored in the location database.
e.g. something like this

```
<div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
    <div v-if="Profile" class="Profile">
<p>Profile.Name<p>
<div v-if="Profile.Location == A >
<p>Only Location A and not location B or any other</div
</div

<div v-else>
      <div class="spin"></div>
     </div>
```

I know that the above <div v-if="Profile.Location == LocA> doesn't work thats how I thought it would be done, I know you can filter profiles based by location like this.

```
const { documents: Profile } = getCollection(
      'Profile', 
      ['Location', '==', 'A']
    )
```

But I can not do that here as I have to display the rest of the documents data just one specific div of the profile page can't be displayed because of the value of the Location in this case. In this example I'm getting the profile after clicking on a users display card which routes me to this page and then using useroute.params.id to get there individual profile.

I've looked through the vue documentation regarding conditional rendering and haven't found away to do this based on the value of the actual location, does anyone know if it is possible to do and if so how do you render only that specific div element based on document data value?

Comment: What does "Location" look like? Once you figure out how to get this "location" from firestore, it should be easy to compare it with something and apply conditional rendering.

Comment: "Location" is just a string value e.g. "Sydney"

Comment: Is it because of typo ? I think you should compare with a string `'A'` instead of just `A`

Comment: Unfortunately not <div v-if="Profile.Location == 'A' > Doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide some script code here, I assume you are using vue 3 and in `<script setup>` format.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
    <div v-if="profile">
      <p>{{ profile.name }}</p>
      <div v-if="isLocationA">
        <p>Only Location A and not location B or any other</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div class="spin"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { doc, getDoc } from '@firebase/firestore';

const route = useRoute();
const db = /* your firebase db instance */
const profileId = route.params.id; 

let error = ref(null);
let profile = ref(null);
let isLocationA = computed(() => profile.value?.location === 'A');

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'Profile', profileId);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      profile.value = docSnap.data();
    } else {
      console.log('No such document!');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    error.value = err;
  }
});
</script>
```

On this way, things are straight forward. you can add locatations based on computed property here just like `isLocationA`.

and also please note that profile is managed based on route params.

Hope this helps!